# Text appear / disappear on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make text appear/disappear on page scroll exactly like in https://www.marqeta.com/ under the heading "Create a tailored payment experience", please can anybody help me how could I achieve that scrolling effect? , I will be very thankful .

Comment: Investigate intersectionObserver, it may help.

Answer (score 2):

The effects on this site are called scroll-based animations. They use different types of scroll animations on this site, but the effect on the section you’re asking about implements a combination of scroll-pinning and scroll-triggered animations.

This can be achieved with a few different libraries or from scratch. Here's an [introduction to scroll animations](https://coolcssanimation.com/how-to-make-scroll-animations/) that I wrote that might help clarify the general ways you can create scroll-based animations.

Since this site has a lot of complex and coordinated scroll animations, they are probably using a scroll animation library like ScrollMagic or GSAP ScrollTrigger. You can investigate those to learn how to create this effect.

You can also create the on scroll text effect from scratch using a combination of `position: sticky` (CSS) to get the text to stay in the same spot and scroll-triggered animations using Intersection Observer (JavaScript).

I created a demo of this effect that you can check out here: https://codepen.io/nickcil/pen/poNZgNq

Answer (score 1):

**The solution (JS, CSS, HTML)**

```js
$(window).on("load",function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowBottom = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight();
    $(".fade").each(function() {
      /* Check the location of each desired element */
      var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      
      /* If the element is completely within bounds of the window, fade it in */
      if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
        if ($(this).css("opacity")==0) {$(this).fadeTo(500,1);}
      } else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
        if ($(this).css("opacity")==1) {$(this).fadeTo(500,0);}
      }
    });
  }).scroll(); //invoke scroll-handler on page-load
});
```

```css
.fade {
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 01</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 02</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 03</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 04</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 05</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 06</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 07</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 08</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 09</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 10</div>
</div>
```